# CMake does not find symbols in static lib that is linked to other static lib

Tags: c++, cmake, linkage

I Have a CMake project that is linked to a static lib LibraryToLink:

```
TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES(${PROJECT_NAME} "LibraryToLink.lib")
```

LibraryToLink was built via Visual Studio and is linked to other static lib OtherStaticLib.lib (defined via VS Project Dependencies)

My Project compiles successfully (all include directories are fine) but fail in linkage.
In my code I am calling class Foo implemented in OtherStaticLib.lib but I fail with error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: __thiscall Foo::Foo(void)"

I can't add OtherStaticLib.lib to TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES because it will cause circular dependencies.

How can I resolve this ?

Comment: Remember that static libraries are really nothing more than a collection of object files, they are not really *linked* like an executable (or shared library). If you depend on a static library A that in turn depends on a library B, then you need to link with both A and B. In that order.

Comment: Regarding the circular dependency, does `OtherStaticLib.lib` depend on `LibraryToLink.lib`? If not then you don't have a circular dependency.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude The *In that order* part is actually toolchain dependent. In CMake, you should always prefer to model all dependencies directly, that is you create two (potentially imported) targets A and B and then use `target_link_libraries` to establish the dependency between them. This is guaranteed to work everywhere and is pretty robust against modifications from colleagues who don't understand how static libraries work.

Comment: Regarding the circular dependency, I have tried to add both LibraryToLink.lib and OtherStaticLib.lib to TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES but than the linker gets into some kind of infinte loop (never finishes)